# Can the Chromium Engine be supported in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, microsoft-edge, chromium, webengine

**Microsoft Edge has officially started using Chromium as its WebEngine.**

Will this change, affect the "WebBrowser" control of VB.net in Visual Studio and if so, how?

Will Internet Explorer's WebEngine Engine, "Trident" or Chromium be used?

Comment: No, WebBrowser always did use the IE render engine.  So Trident.  They are stuck with having to support it for a long time to come.  CefSharp is popular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web browser control in your VB.NET project will not get affected by this change. You can refer to [the documentation of web browser control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-overview) for information on that.

The new changes applied to the **MS Edge WebView2**.

The Microsoft Edge WebView2 control enables you to host web content in your application using Microsoft Edge (Chromium) as the rendering engine.

The WebView2 control is currently in developer preview, during which you can prototype your solutions and share feedback with us to shape the future stable API. There will likely be some breaking changes as we evolve the API during preview, and when this happens, you will need to have both the WebView2 SDK and the Microsoft Edge (Chromium) browser updated. Breaking changes will be noted in the release notes of the SDK. This will lock down as WebView2 approaches beta and stable.

For more information about WebView2, please see [Microsoft Edge WebView2 (developer preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2).